# Creating a running identifier variable in SQL Impala

Tags: sql

I have a variable trade_date that occurs several times in the dataset. I would like to create a variable trade_day that uniquely identifies the trading days by skipping trading days where no trade has occured (e.g. 2016-07-03). The trade_date variable is in date format. How would you do it in SQL Impala?

| trade_date | trade_day |
| --- | --- |
| 2016-07-01 | 20636 |
| 2016-07-01 | 20636 |
| 2016-07-01 | 20636 |
| 2016-07-02 | 20637 |
| 2016-07-02 | 20637 |
| 2016-07-04 | 20639 |
| 2016-07-04 | 20639 |
| 2016-07-04 | 20639 |

Comment: This might help you. `SELECT CAST(CAST('19000101' AS DATETIME) AS INT)`this function returns the days passed until 1900-01-01 therefore it can convert your date values to INT values.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested. The solution is

```
SELECT trade_date,  datediff(CAST(trade_date AS DATE), CAST('2016-07-01' AS DATE)) + 20636 AS trade_day
FROM datashop
GROUP BY trade_date
ORDER BY trade_day
```